# PowerBI percentage calculation

Tags: powerbi, percentage

```
Team   ID   FRUIT
Team1  ID1  apple
Team1  ID2  apple
Team1  ID4  apple
Team1  ID5  apple
Team1  ID6  apple
Team1  ID7  apple
Team1  ID9  apple
Team2  ID11 apple
Team2  ID13 apple
Team2  ID14 apple
Team2  ID15 apple
Team2  ID17 apple
Team1  ID1  pear
Team1  ID4  pear
Team1  ID5  pear
Team1  ID8  pear
Team2  ID13 pear
Team2  ID15 pear
Team2  ID16 pear
Team2  ID17 pear
Team2  ID18 pear
Team2  ID19 pear
Team2  ID20 pear
Team1  ID1  strawberry
Team1  ID5  strawberry
Team2  ID20 strawberry
Team1  ID3  
Team1  ID7
Team1  ID9
Team1  ID10
Team2  ID12
```

I try to calculate in PowerBI:
in each TEAM, the percentage of distinct IDs have each type of FRUIT.
(rows that are blank for FRUIT variable need to be kept, as some IDs don't have FRUIT data, but they need to be counted in the denominator)

My expected outcome is:

```
Team1  apple       70%
Team2  apple       50%
Team1  pear        40%
Team2  pear        70%
Team1  strawberry  20%
Team2  strawberry  10%
Team1              40%
Team2              10%
```

I used the following measure, but did not work, can someone please help? Thanks.

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[ID]), 
    GROUPBY(
        Sheet1, 
        Sheet1[FRUIT]
    )
)/
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[ID]), 
    GROUPBY(
        Sheet1, 
        Sheet1[TEAM]
    )
)
```

Comment: Please add your expected final output from those input data. What do you mean by "have each type of FRUIT"? Is there any separate list of all Fruits? Or you need to make that list from column "FRUIT"?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added the expected outcome as above.

Comment: If you explain at least on calculation like how the first row get 70% will be very helpful.

Comment: Yes. There are a total of 10 distinct IDs in Team1, and there are 7 distinct IDs in Team1 with "apple", so 7 out of 10.

Comment: Last question, you wants a new summarize table? or Measure?

Comment: A measure. In that way I can put a slicer in to display by the type of fruit.

Comment: And, I am getting 9 unique ID for Team 1 and 8 from Team 2

Comment: sorry about that, my manual calculation is incorrect. please move forward with your calculation. The idea is the "7 out of 10" as above comments. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below measure for your purpose. Just change the Measure type to % using the menu bar-

```
team_wise_percentage = 

VAR total_distinct_id = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[ID]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Sheet1),
        Sheet1[Team] = MIN(Sheet1[Team])
    )
)

VAR total_distinct_id_for_current_row_fruit = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[ID]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Sheet1),
        Sheet1[Team] = MIN(Sheet1[Team])
            && Sheet1[FRUIT] = MIN(Sheet1[FRUIT])
    )
)

RETURN total_distinct_id_for_current_row_fruit/total_distinct_id
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have applied this on my big dataset, and it works really well!